# Writing ruby Gnuplot to file

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

I having a problem with saving my `Gnuplot` to file. This is my code:

```
def plot(a, b, name)

  o = Gnuplot.open do |gp|
    Gnuplot::Plot.new( gp ) do |plot|
      plot.title "Wykres funkcji"
      plot.autoscale
      #plot.output name+".svg"
      plot.term "jpeg"
      plot.ylabel "x"
      plot.xlabel "y"
      plot.grid
      x = (a..b) .collect { |v|v.to_f }
      y = x.collect { |v| value(v)}
      plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, y] ) do |ds|
        ds.with = "lines"
      end
    end
    File.open("test.jpeg", "w"){|to_file| Marshal.dump(o, to_file)}
  end
end
```

I don't want to use the output from `Gnuplot`, but I want to do this by `File`. My code creates a file which is empty, or give me an error like:

```
 Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x04 0x08)
```

Can I do this by giving a file as an argument to the function?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot/blob/196043371788cb6f6ab6cd91e7266e808dee4550/examples/output_image_file.rb) of how to output the image to a file, in the project (as referenced in the [README](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot/blob/196043371788cb6f6ab6cd91e7266e808dee4550/README.textile#simple-sin-wave)):

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__))
require "gnuplot"

# See sin_wave.rb first
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  Gnuplot::Plot.new( gp ) do |plot|

    # The following lines allow outputting the graph to an image file. 
    # The first set the kind of image that you want, while the second
    # redirects the output to a given file. 
    #
    # Typical terminals: gif, png, postscript, latex, texdraw
    #
    # See http://mibai.tec.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~oshiro/Doc/gnuplot_primer/gptermcmp.html
    # for a list of recognized terminals.
    #
    plot.terminal "gif"
    plot.output File.expand_path("../sin_wave.gif", __FILE__)

    # see sin_wave.rb
    plot.xrange "[-10:10]"
    plot.title  "Sin Wave Example"
    plot.ylabel "sin(x)"
    plot.xlabel "x"

    plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( "sin(x)" ) do |ds|
      ds.with = "lines"
      ds.linewidth = 4
    end

  end
end
puts 'created sin_wave.gif'
```

At a glance, it looks like your original issue was simply caused by setting `plot.term` instead of `plot.terminal`?

Moreover, I don't see why you need to use `Marshal.dump` and `File.open` - you can just write to a given filename, using `plot.output`, as shown in the example above. Using `Marshal.dump` here won't even work, since you are dumping the whole `Gnuplot` object - which is not just a JPEG file.

If you *really* want to implement your method to take a `File` object, and not just use a filename (string), then you could consider telling `Gnuplot` to write to a [`Tempfile`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), and then copy the `Tempfile` into your own `File` object?

Comment: i know i can write is by use plot.output but can i do it something another without using it?

Comment: Why? And could you use a `Tempfile`?

Comment: I have task to do when is said dont use output. I think using Tempfile isn't too good. Have I any other option maybe using rmagic(i dont know how use it) ?

Comment: You are tasked "not to use `output`", and yet you need to produce an output file? I don't understand. If you are being given a file object, not just a file name, then you can simply use: https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-i-path

Comment: And yes, I agree that `Tempfile` is not a good solution - which is why I'm saying to just use `output`!

Comment: Actually... Again, if you read the README, it seems you could use an arbitrary IO object instead of `Gnuplot.open`: *"When the plot block ends, if an IO object is given to the Plot constructor, the plot commands will be written to the IO object."* But given your code above, this would be pointless ... Unless you are trying to do something more than writing a simple image file!

Comment: That doesn't tmp=File.new("testfile").path  that's correct? And now i can send and save inside my function. Sorry for stupid question but I'm newbie.

Comment: If you have the object: `file = File.new("testfile")` then yes, you could use `plot.output file.path`. But in that case, why are you bothering to pass in a file object in the first place? Just pass in the string `"testfile"`.

Comment: Ok i give up that doesn't work for me i wil probably use plot.output because i dont know how do this another way.

Comment: For future reference... You never attempted to explain *why* you were so against just using `plot.output` (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). "Because I have been told not to" doesn't explain it. If you are trying to do something more complicated (Combining multiple images into one file? Creating an IO stream for another service, without saving to disk? ...) then explain this context in the question.